# Razor Editor Template not getting assigned

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates

We have a collection of Base objects (EndPointBase objects), we would like to display a different editor for each object in the collection (there will be one or more of each EndPoint) so I thought we could use an Editor Template as so:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<AssemblyName.CsvEndPoint>
@if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CsvFileName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CsvFileName)
}
<p>CSV EndPoint Editor Called</p>`
```

This one is for the "CSV" EndPoint however when I call it in code, it outputs the standard template:

```
foreach (var endpoint in Model.Report.EndPoints)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => endpoint)
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong but I'm not sure what, can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I can't answer this for another few hours but incase others need to know -I was naming the editor templates with "Editor" at the end rather than just the Object type which has solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

In case others need to know -I was naming the editor templates with "Editor" at the end rather than just the Object type which has solved the issue e.g. "EndPointBase" was named "EndPointBaseEditor"